# No loading with google map on android studio

Tags: android, dictionary

Nothing wrong in my work I have checked everything literally in my android studio nothing needs to be installed all are installed.the API key is right.
I have added all the permissions and still I get a blank screen like this [photo](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6rDPE.png) And this is my [Log](https://i.stack.imgur.com/R20DV.png) And this is my android [options](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hVX6j.png) And [tools](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VjXwP.png) And here is my [gradl](https://i.stack.imgur.com/B1qiU.png) and [gradl2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eieYk.png)

UPDATE !

I WAS USING VIRTUAL DEVICE THAT DOESN'T SUPPORT ANDROID (NEXUS 5X API 27 GOOGLE PLAY  ANDROID NULL ) SO I HAVE DOWNLOADED OREI API26 ANDROID 8.0 GOOGLE PLAY

THAT'S ALL AFTER ASKING ME TO UPDATE GOOGLE SERVICES THANKS FOR EVERYONE TRIED TO HELP

Comment: 1. Please post the logcat instead of a screenshot. 2. The error is clearly shown in the logcat.

Comment: Have you enabled the service.

Comment: yes ! @ShivamOberoi

Answer (score 0):

You need to Get MapKey & ApiKey from google to use google map and load it

Comment: bro lmfao i have done that already !